# Output of recursive python function

Tags: python, recursion, output

I have a problem with a function which should return all possible combinations in a list, without repeating the sample.

The function works perfectly but I'm unable to get a list of all the combinations:

```
abc = ['a','b','c','d','e']

def combi(pre, listg, stage=1,first = 1):
    if len(listg)==0:
        return []
    start = first
    lifeat =[]
    for i in range(start,len(listg)):
        lifeat.append(pre + [listg[i]])
        print('stage: ',stage,'|| ',i,' ',pre + [listg[i]])
        diff = set(listg[i:]) - set(pre+[listg[i]])
        seted= [item for item in listg[i:] if item in diff]
        li = combi(pre+ [listg[i]],seted,stage+1, first= 0)
        #print('li : ',li)
    return lifeat+li


def all_combi(liste):
    return combi([liste[0]], liste)
all_combi(abc)
```

the printed result :[`print('stage: ',stage,'|| ',i,' ',pre + [listg[i]])`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWDFu.png)

```
stage:  1 ||  1   ['a', 'b']
stage:  2 ||  0   ['a', 'b', 'c']
stage:  3 ||  0   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
stage:  4 ||  0   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
stage:  3 ||  1   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
stage:  2 ||  1   ['a', 'b', 'd']
stage:  3 ||  0   ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']
stage:  2 ||  2   ['a', 'b', 'e']
stage:  1 ||  2   ['a', 'c']
stage:  2 ||  0   ['a', 'c', 'd']
stage:  3 ||  0   ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
stage:  2 ||  1   ['a', 'c', 'e']
stage:  1 ||  3   ['a', 'd']
stage:  2 ||  0   ['a', 'd', 'e']
stage:  1 ||  4   ['a', 'e']
```

This is the output I got : [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIY5u.png)

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd'], ['a', 'e']]
```

thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Show output as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or by external link

Comment: Yeah sorry i though the picture would be shown clearly

Comment: What exactly is the intended output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems in your logic.  I strongly recommend that you use incremental programming to sort out your difficulties.

1. You assume the first element as a required member of every combination.
2. You append only the last value of `li` from your `for` loop; `lifeat` should get them all.

For the second problem, change your return statement to two lines:

```
    lifeat += li
return lifeat
```

This improves your result to

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'e'],
 ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'd'],
 ['a', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'e']]
```

I'll leave the initialisation problem to you.

Comment: Yeah perfect! I was so distract, yeah for the first value it's intended.
I have no idea how to do the same thing in a incremental way.

My first version used `list(itertools.product(*listg))` but it doesn't giving  me all combination, the probleme come from the fact that I need to erase one value at each stage.

Comment: This  one work perfectly, but i'm curious to know how deal with it  with incremental .
What do you mean by _I'll leave the initialisation problem to you_ ?

Comment: @ChrysBltr Problem #1 isn't fixed: every combination starts with the first element, so you're getting less than half..  To fix this, you need to start with an empty list of elements.  I'm leaving that "back up a step" repair to you.

Comment: It's not problem, maybe I should have explain it better, but , in fact I'm using this function for building a machine learning model, so I need to try every combination of feature.
The first feature have to be always in the combination.
Actually the first feature is the departure time  and the model predict delay.
As you might guess, it will be difficult to predict delay if i don't know when I'm leaving.
This is why I added the `first =0` as parameter.

Comment: Ah -- in that case, problem #1 isn't a problem.